# How to check the parameters for a new object in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to create a class called "`items`" with four private `ArrayList<String>` objects with a method that adds items to the ArrayLists depending on what kind of item it is. There are four ArrayLists:

```
private ArrayList<String> itemlistweapons = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> itemlistapparel = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> itemlistaid = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> itemlistmisc = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The method that adds items to the Lists has the following code:

```
public void additem(String name, String type){
    itemlistweapons.add(new Item(name, type).toString());
}
```

The Item object it adds comes from another class called `Item` with a constructor that takes the name of the item and the type.

So, what I'd like to know, is how can I say this:

```
public void additem(String name, String type){
    if //the item added has the type "weapon"
        itemlistweapons.add(new Item(name, type).toString());
    else if //the item added has the type "apparel"
        itemlistapparel.add(new Item(name, type).toString());
    else if //the item added has the type "aid"
        itemlistaid.add(new Item(name, type).toString());
    else if //the item added has the type "misc"
        itemlistmisc.add(new Item(name, type).toString());
```

What would I put in place of those comments?

Comment: `if(type == "weapon")`...

Comment: if ("weapon".equals(type))

Answer (score 2):

```
 if ("weapon".equals(type)) {
```

Notes:

- put the String literal first to avoid NullPointerExceptions
- you should throw an IllegalArgumentException if the given type cannot be handled
- maybe a `switch/case` block is a good alternative
- maybe you want to have `List<Item>` instead of `List<String>`. You can always get the String from the Item, the other way around may be difficult.
- if you have `List<Item>` maybe you don't need four separate lists anymore. Just keep everything in one list. You can always filter on the type to get just the weapons. That would be more flexible.
- maybe type should be an `enum`